# Parametric Equations For A True Egg-shape

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, graphing-functions, conic-sections, parametric

[image]Does anyone know how to formulate a set of parametric equations that generate an egg-shape?

**NOTE.** I've asked several people, including my calculus professor, and in every case, what I got were variations on the standard, symmetrical ellipse. What I want can be defined in a few ways; a form whose curvature is a combination of two or more different ellipses. Or, an egg-shaped section from a 3-d hyperbolic form, i.e., revolve:

$$y=\frac{1}{x}$$

then cut it at an angle yielding an egg-form.

Thank you for your time!

**NOTE.** See fig.

**For My Example**

$$y=\frac{1}{x}$$

$$y=x-2.02$$

Both on the same plane.

Comment: If anyone doesn't get what I mean with the hyperbolic shape, I can do it in solid works and show you; feel free to ask.

Comment: *"If anyone doesn't get what I mean with the hyperbolic shape, I can do it in solid works and show you; feel free to ask."* ... I'm asking. :)

Comment: This is an [old question](https://www.quora.com/What-is-mathematical-equation-for-an-egg).

Comment: With a bit of intentional sarcasm - this is probably going to be closed due to lack of precision. Which egg? Chicken? Duck? Shark?

Comment: A similar question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559756/equation-of-an-egg-formed-after-elliptical-inversion-of-an-ellipse).

Comment: Any egg-shap that is a-symmetrical above and beneath the y axis.

Comment: @JinnyEcckle An intersection of a quadratic surface with a plane is always one of the conic sections - so you probably still end up with an oval if you do it.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I've done this before, so, I can prove it. Give me a few min!

Comment: Your title says "true egg shape", but your description asks to combine curves that arguably won't provide a "true egg shape". I guess it depends upon your definition of "true". ... In any case, have you searched Math.SE for "egg"? For instance, there's [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2890024/409).

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/407454/856, http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/eggcurves.htm, https://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/oeuf/oeuf.shtml.

Comment: To all who doubted what I said, see my image (now in the post).

Comment: @Blue, sorry for the slight lack of rigor; I meant far more true than what I was given. Ideally, it would be a perfect form; but certainly I'd like something better than what I've been given before....

Comment: @StinkingBishop I posted it in my post; so you can see it for yourself....

Comment: To all; in my experience, you can get nearly any egg-shape in the way shown in my photo. The one given is a point-y chicken-egg shape, as seen from some heirloom hens (yes, I've measured this LOL).

Comment: [Netwon's egg](http://www.2dcurves.com/cubic/cubicn.html#Newtonseggcurve) $y^2 = (x^2-1)(x-a)$, $(a \sim 3)$,
[Cubic egg](http://www.2dcurves.com/cubic/cubiceg.html) $x^2 + y^2(1+ax) = 1$, $(a < 1)$, [Wassenaar (egg)](http://www.2dcurves.com/quartic/quartice.html) $(y-x^2)^2 = 1-ax^2$, $(a \sim 5)$....

Comment: There is no *true* (chicken) egg shape afik . Inversions of  some eccentric  ellipses  about a circle contour when used as circle of inversion produce egg profiles of reasonably accurate shape... imho.

Comment: @Narasimham
The validity of your statement depends on whether or not on is a Platonist......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intersecting the surface $z=1/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ with a plane $z=kx+b$ gives a curve in 3-space. Rotating this curve by $\arctan k$ about the $y$-axis gives a curve in a plane parallel to $(xy)$-plane, having parametric equations (for $b^2\ge4k$):
$$
\begin{align}
&x={1\over2\sqrt{1+k^2}}
\left({k^2-1\over k}b+{k^2+1\over k}\sqrt{b^2-4k\cos t}\right)\\
\\
&y={2\sin t\over b+\sqrt{b^2-4k\cos t}}\\
\end{align}
$$
This can give an egg shape for suitable values of $b$ and $k$. Here's the result for $k=1$ and $b=2.02$:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner. This is absolutely brilliant! And, seeing what and how you did this will make this subject very cool to play around with. Seeing that you're a physics guy, I see why you got what I meant.

Lovely, elegant work!