# Apart from ellipses and using polynomials (Lagrange interpolation formula), what other mathematical methods could I use to model an oval shape?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Part of my homework is to model an egg using different mathematical methods and then evaluating both approaches. I have already found that this is possible if I were to use ellipses equations and Lagrange Interpolation formula however I do want to use another approach if it is appropriate.

Note I am modeling an egg by using a 2d photo and interposing it on a graphing software (GeoGebra/desmos). I am want to use the function/expressions that I find to calculate the volume and surface area of the egg.

I would appreciate it if I could insight into other viable mathematical approaches other than those listed above.

Comment: Uh, conical sections?

Comment: You could model an egg pretty well using two [metaballs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaballs) with two different weights.

Comment: See this question, and above all the links given in the comments to it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3375853/parametric-equations-for-a-true-egg-shape

Comment: And this page too: http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/eggcurves.htm